# Bulletproof seeding of random generators to ensure computational reproducibility in Python

Tags: python, random, numpy-random

My intention is to create a guideline on how to do **reproducible computations** in Python (if possible, regardless the environment, the operating system, etc.). However the issue of **generating random numbers** keeps coming back to my mind. I am struggling to find a bulletproof way (if there is one).

Standard way how to make the output of **random generators reproducible** is to use

```
import random
random.seed()
```

As far as I know, the automatic choice of the seed is dependent on the system. (See [random.seed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed)'s documentation in Python.)

A better way is therefore to use specific number to seed the generator.

```
import random
random.seed(0)
```

However, there are libraries that does not use built-in random but rather use `numpy.random`. Therefore you also need to seed `numpy`'s generator.

```
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(0)
```

Built-in `random` works as a singleton and I suppose `numpy.random` works the same way. It means that you set the seed once and then it is used everywhere.

I would like to create a code snippet which you could use at the beginning of your code and which would ensure the computational reproducibility in terms of random generators.

Is there any better way then **combining both generators** and setting both seeds and possibly even keeping the reproducibility **across operating systems**? 
And are you familiar with any **widely used pseudo-random generators** that should be added to built-in random and to numpy random generators in order to make the snippet as general as possible?

Comment: Don't use 0 as a seed.  Some generators react badly to a 0 seed.  Pick 42 or some other positive number instead.

Comment: there are other factors that will vary beyond random numbers, such as `dict` or `set` iteration order- these could be partially dealt with by fixing the `PYTHONHASHSEED` variable